# Must a vertical sundial face exactly South?

Tags: sun, home-experiment

> I am a sundial. I'm prepared to bet
>   Your watch can't tell when the sun will set

I once heard [Frank King talk](http://issuu.com/sel-alum/docs/selwyn_articles_in_british_sundial_society_journal) about sundials in particular this very cool one, which measures Babylonian hours (hours since sunrise) and Italian hours (hours since sunset)

I am moving house and thinking about making my own, but none of the walls face exactly South. One of the walls faces approximately South-southeast (haven't measured exactly yet).

Would it still be possible to make a sundial like that? I understand it would be shaded for the last couple hours of the day (when the sun is in the west)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questioner says that he once heard a Frank King talk and then asks about designing a sundial that indicates Babylonian Hours and Italian Hours when the dial doesn't face due south.  The sundial that was the subject of Frank King's talk doesn't face due south either.  I suggest the questioner gets in touch with Frank King who might be able to advise.

Frank King

Comment: I observe that the questioner already appears to be in touch with Frank King through this website and I suggest that the advice is given on this website. I am sure it makes an interesting read which contributes to this site.

Comment: -1 while entertaining, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

A vertical sundial that *doesn't* face N, E, S, or W is called a [vertical *declining* dial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial#Vertical_declining_dials). Formulae are in the link.

I don't know if, for such dials, there is any inherent difficulty with Babylonian or Italian hours. Ask [Frank King](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=IYCIya__Vrg#t=53s).

By the way, there is a *staggering* amount of information on sundials available on the Internet. One may start with the Wikipedia link provided above, or [here](http://www.sundialsoc.org.uk/weblinks.php#sundialsocs).